# Retain cycle in AFNetworking success block

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

Usually, Xcode shows a warning when using a strong reference in a block (retain cycle). However, I don't understand why it doesn't show it with this `AFNetworking` example.

```
UIImageView *imageView;
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [apiQueryManager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSData *responseObject) {
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseObject];
     imageView.image =image;  // <--- using strong ref to imageView ?
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
}];
[apiQueryManager enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Is there a retain cycle here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a retain cycle because of `imageView`, `imageView` would need to have a strong reference to the block in which it is used. This is not the case.

Comment: In your example, Noe, a retain cycle would occur if `operation` is used within the block.

Comment: Ok I get it now :) Thank you both
And by the way, I think AFNetworking gives the parameters of the success block as weak references (if I'm not mistaken), so, @GuyKogus, there would be no retain cycle ?

Comment: A retain cycle often occurs when an object retains a block which retains that object (sounds confusing, I know). When you call a block, the parameters being passed into it are not retained in the block object (yes, blocks are objects), so there's no retain cycle.